# qt gui global variables

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I created a Qt gui with c++ and I'm compiling it with cmake. Below you can find my CMakeLists.

```
**CMakeLists**
#My CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8) project (teste)

#---------------------------------

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED) INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE}) ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

SET(teste_SOURCES main.cpp mainwindow.cpp) SET(teste_FORMS mainwindow.ui) SET(teste_HEADERS mainwindow.h globals.h) set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON) set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

QT4_WRAP_CPP(teste_HEADERS_MOC ${SimpleProject_HEADERS}) QT4_WRAP_UI(teste_FORMS_HEADERS ${SimpleProject_FORMS})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}) ADD_EXECUTABLE(teste
    ${teste_SOURCES}
    ${teste_HEADERS_MOC}
    ${teste_FORMS_HEADERS} )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(teste ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

In my Qt GUI I created some global variables (globals.h) and now I want my ROS node to get those variables.

```
**globals.h**

 #ifndef GLOBALS_H

#define GLOBALS_H

// ALL THE GLOBAL DECLARATIONS

extern int numberOfMotors;
extern int intensidade[16];
extern int local[16];

#endif // GLOBALS_H
```

I assume that I have to include globals.h in my ROS node and then act conform it. However, I don't know how to make the globals.h available for ROS. I think I need to probably mix my cmake makefile and my catkin_make makefile, but I have no idea how.
Here's my catkin_make CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(tentativa)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
 message_generation
  message_runtime
)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   Dados.msg
   Dados2.msg
 )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
 )

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime #rwsua2017_msgs
)
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(publish_arduino src/publish_arduino.cpp)
target_link_libraries(publish_arduino ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(publish_arduino tentativa_generate_message_cpp)
```

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259714/qt-gui-global-variables/) by [jonagf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29777/jonagf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not how global variables work. Global variables are only accessible from within a separate process. You have two executables (`teste` and `publish_arduino`), so the information will not be shared between them, even if both include `globals.h`.

If you want to share information between the two processes, you should look at using shared memory, or (since you are on a ROS forum) making your Qt GUI a node and using a topic to pass the information.

As an aside, in general global variables are a bad idea. Do not use global variables without a good reason.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jonagf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29777/jonagf/) on 2017-04-24**:
I'm gonna try that. Thank you!